# from ggplotly, open all new hyperlinks in the same new window/tab

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly, htmlwidgets

I am using the following example code where click on the point opens a link:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$urlD <- paste0("http://google.com/search?q=", gsub(" ", "+", rownames(mtcars)))

p <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=factor(carb), customdata=urlD)) + geom_point() 
pp <- ggplotly(p)
ppp <- htmlwidgets::onRender(pp, "
     function(el, x) {
       el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
         var url = d.points[0].customdata;
         window.open(url);
       });
     }
  ")
```

It works fine but every new click opens *new* window/tab. Is there any way to make it use the same window? (I mean not the window with the plot but the window where the first link was opened) In usual javascript, I would use the `name` parameter of `window.open()`, like this: `window.open(url, 'MyTargetWindow');` - but it doesn't help here. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using Rstudio. `window.open(url, 'MyTargetWindow')` works in browser but not in Rstudio. If you click the "show in new window" button and open the plot in your browser, it works. The reason is window `name` is recognized in the same browser, but when you open a new browser (from Rstudio Viewer to the actual browser in this case), the `name` info is not passed. I am not aware of a solution to solve this cross-browser issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're right, I should have checked that first. Thanks!